# SwiftUI - Dismiss modal after navigating through several screens

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a flow that is originally presented like this:

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: SomeRootView())
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(vc, animated: true)
```

From that view/screen, I can dismiss it via `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

However, after navigating through several screens in that flow using this kind of thing:

```
NavigationLink(destination: SomeOtherView(), isActive: $viewModel.shouldProceed) { EmptyView() }
```

When I dismiss from any other view, it just goes back one level in the navigation stack. What I want is to dismiss the entire nav stack. What's the cleanest way to do this? I need to have the option to dismiss the entire flow at any point during the navigation.